# Heuristic for lower bounding the time for integer factorization?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, factorization, heuristics

I am posting this question here in hope that someone finds this heuristic useful, and maybe someone with more experience will make use of this:

As @GerryMyerson suggested here is a statement of what I am trying to prove:
There is no "simplified" algorithm, which can factor integers in polynomial time. The word "simplified" is described in more detail below.

First notice that $\exists d: 1 < d < n , d | n$ is equivalent to $\exists x: 1 < \gcd(x,n) < n$.

Let $A$ be a general purpose factorization algorithm which in every step $1,\cdots,t$ draws a number without replacement $a_i \in \mathbb{N}$ from the urn $\{m_n,m_n+1,\cdots,M_n-1,M_n\}$ and tests if $ 1 < \gcd(a_i,n) < n$ ($A$ = "simplified" algorithm). 
Besides the heuristic, that the numbers are drawn without replacement, some general purpose algorithms operate this way, for example the Fermat - Factorization, trial divison, or even Quadratic sieve. 
The point here is that the algorithm generates "candidate" numbers $a_i$ in each step and tests if those number represent a "solution". Let $Y$ be the waiting time until the first $a_i$ is found with $1 < \gcd(a_i,n) < n$, after which the algorithm stopps and prints $\gcd(a_i,n)$.
Let $d_n$ count the number of $k$, $m_n \le k \le M_n$ such that $1 < \gcd(a_k,n) < n$ and $N_n = M_n-m_n+1$. Then we will have
$$d_n \approx N_n ( \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{n})$$
if $n=pq$ is the prime decomposition of $n$. Letting 
$$p \approx q \approx \sqrt{n}$$
we get 
$$d_n \approx N_n ( \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{n})$$

The random variable $Y$ is negatively hypergeometrically distributed with expected value:

$$t = E[Y] = \frac{N_n+1}{d_n+1} \approx \frac{N_n}{d_n}$$

a) Suppose $t \le \log(n)^c$ is an upper bound on the expected runtime of the algorithm. Then:

$$ 1 \le \log(n)^c (\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{n}) \rightarrow 0$$
for $n \rightarrow \infty$, which is impossible. Hence no such upper bound can exist.

b) If $t\le \sqrt{n}$ is an upper bound, then

$$ 1 \le \sqrt{n}(\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{n}) = 2 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $$
which has for $n \rightarrow \infty$ limit $=2$ and hence no contradiction arises.

c) If $t \le \exp(\sqrt{\log(n)\log(\log(n))})$ then we will get similar to a) a contradiction $1 \le 0$. Hence sub-exponential time can not be reached with "simplified" algorithms. (Since Quadratic Sieve has sub-exponential time, this means, either that "simplified" algorithms are too restrictive, or that one has first to do a de-randomization, if possible, of the "simplified" algorithm.)

My question is, if you can think of better ways, more rigorous, to replace various steps in this heuristic with more robust arguments?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is no statement of what it is that you are trying to prove here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I am trying to prove, that certain kind of "simplified" algorithms, can not do factorization fast.

Comment: What's missing is a simple, clear statement of the result you are trying to prove.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Ok thanks I changed this.

Comment: Cross-posted to https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/44120/heuristic-for-lower-bounds-in-integer-factorization

Comment: @EmilJerabek: thanks. i posted this here and there since i was not sure which is the best place to post

Comment: When you're not sure where to post, you post to **one** and then wait a week and if nothing happens **then** you post to the other. Also, when you do post to a second site, you post links at each site to the post at the other.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ok thanks. i will keep that in mind for the next time.